# Problems with architecture of the redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm developing an application that has several states (reducers). Let's say they are messages, likes, comments (all of them are from the completely different instances so i'm not sure if i should combine them into one state).

Every 30 seconds i make request to the server and i receive response that says which parts of my application have been updated. E.g. i received new messages or new comment.

I don't really know how to handle those responses. First, i can simply let container update all other states, but i don't think that it's a good idea, because every container should have it's own state.

Second, i can create a middleware that will catch every action, find the one with required information and shot another action (e.g. new message). After that reducer of the messages will catch this action. But i'm not sure again if this is a correct approach for two reasons:

1. Is it okay to shot actions from the middleware (won't it be a bidirectional flow)?
2. How can i actually do it?

Thanks in advance.

UPD. I did it using middleware, but i'm still not sure if this is a correct way. In my middleware i obtain required data using store.getState()... and then i make store.dispatch(myAction). Is it okay?

Answer (score 1):

It's important to understand that a reducer /= state. ( reducer not equal state )

You should have one state, one store for your application. Use combineReducers to well.. combine reducers to keep everything in one state.

http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html

You need to handle async behaviour, something which is not default by redux and therefore you have to use some kind of middleware - meaning you were on the right track.

Try and use the more common once like:
https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk
https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga

It's advised to separate the async logic from your app. Meaning you need to init your async calling in the app, but keep the async logic in the store.

Here's a guide by Dan Abramov and Redux-Thunk which is simple and clear:
http://redux.js.org/docs/advanced/AsyncActions.html

Hope it answers you.